# Access Gitlab CE API from within CI Job without Personal Access Token?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

There is a way to authenticate for calls to the Gitlab API from within CI Jobs with the [`CI_JOB_TOKEN`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#ci-job-token) variable, but this seems to only work on the *Enterprise Edition Premium*, neither *Community  Edition* nor the *Enterprise Edition Starter*.

Is there any way to access the Gitlab CI API (e.g. for downloading artifacts and querying jobs) without having to use the personal access token of a regular user (which would require a dedicated user to stay secure) for *Community Edition* or *Enterprise Starter*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe not. The only way would indeed be to create a user with an access token and inject that through CI secrets.